# Awkward horizontal center alignment

Tags: html

Anyone have any ideas how I can horizontally center the following page.  As you can see the table section can be easily centered but how to do the same with the group of absolute positioned div's.

http://gideaparkbowlingclub.associateddata.co.uk/1a.htm

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a wrapper for all of your absolutely-positioned DIVS, and set it as `position:relative`. That way the DIVs find their origin in the wrapper. Then you just have to center the wrapper DIV.

```
.wrapper {
   width:805px;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   position:relative
}
```

P.S. using absolute positioning for everything is a bad idea. Learn how to use floats.

Comment: Thanks Diodeus, what I actually ended-up with is:.wrapper {
  width:805px;
  top: -637px;
  margin: auto;
  position:relative;"
 }

Comment: I know absolute positioning is bad but I did not write this site, just trying to fix it and make the most of a bad job.

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the content inside a `<div class="content">` with the following CSS

```
.content {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

When you absolutely position something inside an element that is relatively positioned the absolute position is relative to that outer element. So your images should not overflow this new div that you insert the content.

Comment: Works fine in Firefox but not in IE which seems to just ignore the margins.

Comment: Did you use the correct doctype? If the doctype is incorrect IE renders the page in quirks mode. <!doctype html> works for HTML5, for HTML4 use [one of these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration#HTML_4.01_DTDs)